# Printing a compile-time string_view

Tags: c++, c++20

Say I have a metafunction that returns a `std::string_view`

```
template<typename T>
struct type_to_string;

template <typename T>
constexpr std::string_view type_to_string_v = type_to_string<T>::value;
```

and a string_view resulting from this:

```
constexpr auto sv = type_to_string_v<very_complex_expression>;
```

Is there any way to print the value of this string at compile-time? (ie. as part of some compiler error message or static assert)

Comment: You don't have a template function, you have a template variable. Each specialisation is a default initialised `std::string_view`

Comment: What you have written doesn't look like a template function.

Comment: That doesn't even make sense. All you're doing is initializing the `sv` variable using the default-constructed (and therefore empty) `type_to_string_v<very_complex_expression>` variable. And `very_complex_expression` can't be an expression, it must be a *type* (which isn't really used).

Comment: You can't really print things at compile time since you don't actually have a program yet, you are in the process of creating one?  What are you trying to solve by being able to print at compile time?

Comment: Edit: I changed the terminology from "template function" to metafunction and updated the example to be less confusing.

Comment: @康桓瑋 No, not related at all.

Comment: There is no standard way to issue an error message which is not literally embedded in a program text.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. It seems to me that the OP's intent was to get a string of type `very_complex_expression` at compile time. Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @康桓瑋 You're misunderstanding, the intent is to get the value of the string_view `type_to_string<very_complex_expression>::value`, that is defined somewhere else in the program. (but to figure out where would be, well, very complex) I'm also not necessarily looking for an automated or standards-compliant way, the intent is mainly to help with debugging compile-time issues.

Comment: In principle this *should* be possible, since `string_view::size()` and `string_view::starts_with()` are also constexpr, so one could imagine implementing a binary search over all possible characters in all places. But it feels like there should be a better way to do this.

Comment: If you can replace `string_view` with a custom structural type, you can achieve this with mainstream compilers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a modification of OP's solution that produces a somewhat more readable message with gcc. Unfortunately, with clang the message is rather less readable, and MSVC doesn't work at all (due to a compiler bug I suppose).

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string_view>
#include <utility>

template <size_t N> struct FS {             // fixed size string
  char chars[N + 1] = {};
  constexpr FS(const char (&str)[N + 1]) {
      std::copy_n(str, N + 1, chars); 
  }
};

template <size_t N> FS(const char (&str)[N])->FS<N - 1>;

template<typename T>
struct type_to_string;

template<>
struct type_to_string<int> { constexpr static auto value = "integer"; };

template <auto>
constexpr bool string_value = false;

template<FS fs>                             // size will be deduced
void compile_time_display() {
        static_assert(string_value<fs>);
}

int main()
{
    constexpr std::string_view sv = type_to_string<int>::value;
    constexpr size_t n = sv.size();
    constexpr auto indices = std::make_index_sequence<n>();

    [&] <std::size_t... I>
        (std::index_sequence<I...>)
        {
            static constexpr char text[] { (char)sv.at(I)..., 0 };
            compile_time_display<text>();    // the char array will convert to FS

        }(indices);
}
```

The message shown by gcc reads:

```
main.cc: In instantiation of ‘void compile_time_display() 
     [with FS<...auto...> fs = FS<7>{"integer"}]’
...
main.cc:26:23: note: ‘string_value<FS<7>{"integer"}>’ evaluates to false
```

Answer (score 1):

C++ has no mechanism to "print" anything at compile-time. Constant evaluation has no input or output mechanism. `static_assert`s can be used to display messages, but they specifically take string literals.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that this can be done in a relatively straightforward way by destructuring the `string_view` into a list of chars. Here's a complete example extending the setup from the original question:

```
#include <string_view>
#include <utility>

template<typename T>
struct type_to_string;

template<>
struct type_to_string<int> { constexpr static auto value = "integer"; };

template <char... T>
constexpr bool string_value = false;

template<char... c>
void compile_time_display() {
        static_assert(string_value<c...>);
}

int main() {
        constexpr std::string_view sv = type_to_string<int>::value;
        constexpr size_t n = sv.size();
        constexpr auto indices = std::make_index_sequence<n>();

        [&] <std::size_t... I>
           (std::index_sequence<I...>)
        {
                compile_time_display<sv.at(I)...>();
        }(indices);
}
```

Popular compilers display the string value prominently:

```
$ g++ sv_to_array.cpp
sv_to_array.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void compile_time_display() [with char ...c = {'i', 'n', 't', 'e', 'g', 'e', 'r'}]’:
sv_to_array.cpp:26:36:   required from ‘main()::<lambda(std::index_sequence<I ...>)> [with long unsigned int ...I = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}; std::index_sequence<I ...> = std::integer_sequence<long unsigned int, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6>]’
sv_to_array.cpp:27:3:   required from here
sv_to_array.cpp:15:23: error: static assertion failed
   15 |         static_assert(string_value<c...>);
      |                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
sv_to_array.cpp:15:23: note: ‘string_value<'i', 'n', 't', 'e', 'g', 'e', 'r'>’ evaluates to false
```

```
$ clang++ sv_to_array.cpp -std=c++20
sv_to_array.cpp:15:2: error: static_assert failed due to requirement 'string_value<'i', 'n', 't', 'e', 'g', 'e', 'r'>'
        static_assert(string_value<c...>);
        ^             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
sv_to_array.cpp:26:3: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'compile_time_display<'i', 'n', 't', 'e', 'g', 'e', 'r'>' requested here
                compile_time_display<sv.at(I)...>();
                ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: `'i', 'n', 't', 'e', 'g', 'e', 'r'` instead of `"integer"` is rather unfortunate. I have code that makes gcc display `"integer"` but clang displays `{105, 110, 116, 101, 103, 101, 114, 0}`, and msvc doesn't work at all (compiler bug/unimplemented language feature?).

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. You should consider posting it as a separate answer, having something that works with gcc can be useful enough in many situations.